# Let's synonymize a few plural, unnecessary tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

We have a few tags which should be synonymized!

[identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/identifiers) (51) has the same tag wiki as [identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/identifier) (641), and are synonymous:

> An identifier is a name that identifies either a unique object or a unique class of objects.

Next is the [directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directories) (446) tag, which simply just says the following in its excerpt:

> Use the [directory] tag instead

It should be synonymized into [directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directory) (5,069).

The [direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/direction) (315) tag is a very meta tag, and doesn't have a tag excerpt or tag wiki to help users use the tag properly. It should / could be synonymized into [directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directions) (190), which includes a helpful tag excerpt and tag wiki.

[cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cipher) (0) was synonymized into [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption) (14,259), but [ciphers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ciphers) (67) wasn't, and there is no tag excerpt or wiki for the tag to demonstrate differences between the tag and ciphering. It should be synonymized into [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption) as well.

Unfortunately, I myself do not have enough tag score in any of the fields to propose the tag synonyms.

Comment: those 51 and 67 can be retagged by hand and will then be removed at 03:00 UTC...

Comment: On second thought. I've looked through [direction] and [directions]. They should not be synonymized. [directions] is about navigation using some maps API, but [direction] is mostly about moving something on screen. There are some questions about [directions] in there though, so they should be retagged. For example all of them [direction] [google-maps].

Comment: If it's salvageable, can you edit the tag wiki to complete the field? @ArtjomB.

Comment: [map-directions] (83Q - no wiki) should be synonymized to [directions]

Comment: @ArtjomB. I totally think that it should be backwards.

Comment: I was working on re-tagging the 51 and 67 because it was suggested here.  My edits are all being rejected, should I not be doing this?

Comment: I feel that it is useful to have a separate, more specific, "ciphers" tag about the choice of ciphers in TLS software. (For example, "How do I disable SSL 3.0" => "Use Cipher List SECURE128:-VERS-SSL3.0")

Comment: @hosch250 You should fix every problem in the post along with retagging. Leaving problems within the post while retagging is a waste of reviewers' time.

Comment: @Unihedron OK, I finished retagging, and I removed some content that is now banned ("problem" in the title, for example).  I will certainly remember this for the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/identifiers) should have been retagged and now has no more questions.

[direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/direction) tag has been improved and is now no longer synonymous to [directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directions), so it can live.

I've also went through and retagged what's still there of [ciphers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ciphers), and they now point to the correct tags ([ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssl), [tls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tls), [aes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aes) et cetera). [ciphers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ciphers) now has no more questions.

However, the [directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directories) tag still has to be dealt with.

---

As of Fri May 01 15:48:23 2015 UTC, [directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directories) is synonymized to [directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directory) thanks to [animuson♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson).