# Let's put an end to this! Or an s...?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I came across [graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphic). It has no wiki or usage guidance, (but over 400 questions) though the [graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphics) tag also exists.

Hey Green slim mutated Dragonite,

[image: tag burninated],

I have something that you might want to take a look at. Of course, we can make that a synonym instead!

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: What about making a synonym instead?

Comment: @Tunaki that's why I said "or an s"! :)

Comment: Related [Let's synonymize a few plural, unnecessary tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275672)

Comment: Meh, 10% of these questions have score <=-1, 8% closed and only 4% score over 10. I would say that cleaning up (closing, deleting) would be more productive. Start here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[graphic]+[linux]+is%3Aq

Comment: Errata: score over 10 is just the 2%. Forgot to exclude answers.